# xampp Apache 1.8.1 localhost error 404/403

Tags: apache, xampp

I updated xampp from 1.8.0 to 1.8.1 and things didn't work out afterwards. I googled my problems, tried to change stuff and got more problems in the end.

I don't know what to do with the output in the error.log:

- [Tue Jan 01 22:34:05.546412 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 5536:tid 376] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
- [Tue Jan 01 22:34:05.627417 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5536:tid 376] AH00455: Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
- [Tue Jan 01 22:34:05.627417 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5536:tid 376] AH00456: Server built: Aug 18 2012 12:41:37
- [Tue Jan 01 22:34:05.627417 2013] [core:notice] [pid 5536:tid 376] AH00094: Command line: 'D:\portableapps\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe -d D:/PortableApps/xampp/apache'
- [Tue Jan 01 22:34:05.628417 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5536:tid 376] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5672
- [Tue Jan 01 22:34:06.592472 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 5672:tid 268] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
- [Tue Jan 01 22:34:06.629474 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5672:tid 268] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.

Comment: Where is your web root directory located?

Comment: Do you mean: DocumentRoot "D:/PortableApps/xampp/htdocs" ?

Comment: You removed that lines from your question but I think you need to reconfigure the `DocumentRoot`. It seems to be broken actually it points to `D:/htdocs/kamino/`.

Comment: I reinstalled xampp, but I still get the error above

Comment: Wow. You try to use ssl on an MS-Windows based http server? Rarely seen such a setup...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rename .htaccess to htaccess - Either the Problem lies in there or there is some other server configuration issue.